# splunk date time difference

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

I am new to Splunk. My goal is to optimize the API call, since that particular API method is taking more than 5 minutes to execute.

In Splunk I searched using context ID, I got all the functions and sub functions call by main API call function for that particular execution. Now I want to figure what which sub function took the maximum time. In Splunk in left side, in the list of fields, I see field name CallStartUtcTime (e.g. "2021-02-12T20:17:42.3308285Z") and CallEndUtcTime (e.g. "2021-02-12T20:18:02.3702937Z"). In search how can I write a function which will give me difference between these two times. I google and found we can use eval() function but for me its returning null value.

Additional Info:

search: [image: context id and eval in search]

clicked on "create table view" and checked start, end and diff fields in the left side fields list. but all three are coming as null

[image]

not sure what wrong I am doing. I want to find out the time taken by each function.

Answer (score 2):

Splunk cannot compare timestamps in string form.  They must be converted to epoch (integer) form, first.  Use the `strptime()` function for that.

```
...
| eval start = strptime(CallStartUtcTime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%7N%Z")
| eval end = strptime(CallEndUtcTime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%7N%Z")
| eval diff = end - start
...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am getting diff field as null. I use context id and the eval statement you sent so my search is.

Comment: d47fa1ad-d9a1-4fce-a1af-2a33f839a28e | eval start = strptime(CallStartUtcTime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%7N%Z") | eval end = strptime(CallEndUtcTime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%7N%Z") | eval diff = end - start

Comment: d47fa1ad-d9a1-4fce-a1af-2a33f839a28e  is the context id.

Comment: even start and end fields are null. to see these fields (start, end and diff), I added text mentioned above "d47fa1ad-...diff = end - start" in the search text box. and click on "create table view" and then checked "start", "end" and "diff" to show these columns in table view. But all three columns are coming as null.

Comment: Here is a run-anywhere example using data from the original question.

`| makeresults`
`| eval CallStartUtcTime="2021-02-12T20:17:42.3308285Z", CallEndUtcTime="2021-02-12T20:18:02.3702937Z"`
`| eval start = strptime(CallStartUtcTime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%7N%Z")`
`| eval end = strptime(CallEndUtcTime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%7N%Z")`
`| eval diff = end - start`
`| table CallStartUtcTime CallEndUtcTime start end diff`